# How do I need to configure SMTP Auth?

Tags: 7, emails

I have dedicated FreeBSD box, The email sending **without** [smtp module](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) is working perfectly but very slow. The receiver receives email after almost 15 mins. I checked the `maillog` it says `delays` and `timeouts` that means the server keeps on trying to send email again and again until it successfully sends one. This is consuming lots of CPU.

I am seeking help for configuring `smpt module` to use my dedicated box's  `smtp server`,
I need help in following places where I have `????` sign:

```
#SMTP server settings
SMTP server -> smpt.mydomain.com  # Tested by pinging, its working
SMTP backup server -> mail.mydomain.com  # Also verified by Ping
SMTP port -> 25
USE SSL

#SMTP Authentication
Username -> ???????
Password -> ???????
```

I tried using `localhost`, also username and password of the dedicated box or leaving both lines blank which gives me:

> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem
>   persists.

also checking the `debug log` doesn't show any log, it says check `admin/reports/dblog` but when I got to the link it just shows me the contents from `admin/reports` no any `dblog`

Comment: As regards the absence of reports it sounds like you haven't got DB logging turned on. You need to enable the core Database Logging module. Also I am not sure that sending to a local SMTP server will solve your delivery problem. Why so many retries? An SMTP server may perform as badly as your MTA, if it's something like a local DNS issue, for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the `Core->Database Log` I turned it `on` and I can see the log now. I can successfully send test email using `gmail smtp` but when I send other emails I get `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't so difficult to use my hosting providers smtp, instead of having my own. What I did is:

```
#SMTP server settings
SMTP server -> smpt.myhostingprovider.com
SMTP backup server -> mail.myhostingprovider.com
SMTP port -> 25
USE SSL

#SMTP Authentication
Username -> my-email@myhostingprovider.com
Password -> my email's password
```

Now, it is working perfectly, no delays !!!

Answer (score 0):

Most providers block smtp ports, I had to use a [mail redirection service](http://dyn.com/email/dyn-email-gateway/) when I set this up.

If the message gets through after 15 minutes though, I suspect you have a  mail server misconfiguration. Nowadays, I usually go for a much simpler approach, I use google's [smtp server to send the emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939238/gmail-smtp-configuration-for-drupal-7).

An easy way you can test if port 25 is blocked is by connecting by SSH to a remote server, then trying to telnet on local server port 25.

```
telnet mail.port25.com 25
```

If the port is open, you should get a response similar to this:

```
Trying 69.63.149.30...
Connected to mail.port25.com (69.63.149.30).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.port25.com (PowerMTA(TM) v4.0) ESMTP service ready
```

Another thing to check, if you are using qmail make sure the trigger file has proper permissions. `qmail/queue/lock/trigger` should be `prw--w--w qmails:qmail`.

Comment: Yes I get the same response as you said for `telnet` and only port 25 is open for mail server. I could have used `gmail` but it sends email with `myinfo@gmail.com` however I want to send it via `info@mydomain.com`. I don't know about misconfiguration in mail server, as I haven't configured one. Without even touching it the mail was transferred (although slow) so, I haven't done anything in mail server settings.