# Errors when trying to send e-mail when using Ubercart

Tags: 7, users, emails, ubercart

I am aware of the many other:

> Unable to send e-mail. Please contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

Questions that have been asked however, I believe my situation to be a bit different.

Situation:

I have been tasked to make some updates to my companies website. They are hosted and use cpanel for management. I have been working with the Drupal portion of the site and have been getting the Unable to send e-mail error when trying to do any of the following:

- Create a user account
- Retrieve lost password
- Use any of the e-mail functions in Ubercart (order confirmation ect..)

Question:

Are there any settings that I should be looking to change or is this something that needs to be configured in a config file. I have set and e-mail up for (Home » Administration » Store » Configuration) in Ubercart.

Things I have tried:

I have set and e-mail up for (Home » Administration » Store » Configuration) in Ubercart. I have also set up the site e-mail (Home » Administration » Configuration » System).

Comment: Has this site ever been able to send mail? Could be server config

Comment: The site was just transferred to a new server a few days ago and has not worked since. As far as on the first server, I am not sure. The site was previously handled by an employee who was fired and he left no documentation that it worked on the first server.

Comment: If it is as you say and the server needs configured, is that something that can be done while it's on a hosted server through cPanel or WHM?

Comment: I wouldn't be sure how to troubleshoot from cPanel or WHM. Does your @domain email go through this server? Do you have command line access? I don't think WHM shows maillog.  If you login to cPanel, on the left column you should see `path to sendmail`.  In WHM, you can look at Mail Server Configuration and see if anything doesn't look right.  If you have command line, `tail -n 20 /var/log/maillog`

Comment: @bloomm09 I was able to send mails from a page hosted on cPanel managed site. I simply filled a sysadmin issue ticket to get the job done, as by default it did not work.

Comment: Good luck. I wish I could help you more, but nothing available in cPanel helped me back then. either mail() function must work, or you must have smtp server you can use with [smtp module](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) - I saw no option for either of them in cPanel.

Comment: @Molot  What information did you have to include and was it a ticket to your host or your local sysadmin? Thanks

Comment: It was a bit of a special situation, but long story short it was sent to a hosting company. Basically we asked to make mail() function work, or provide instructions for proper SMTP mail sending if that's the way supported by them. We got both. Then, we needed our local sysadmin to whitelist our web server, but that's another story ;)

Comment: Ok thanks, just sent a trouble ticket out so I guess we will see!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17291/unable-to-send-e-mail-contact-the-site-administrator-if-the-problem-persists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much searching I came across this post:

http://shutterfreak.net/blogs/olivier-biot/2010-06-24/configuring-smtp-server-sending-mail-drupal

Apparently issues with the default SMTP are quite common. This post explains how to install and configure "SMTP Authentication Support module" and PHPmailer to basically override the default.

Worked great for me.