# SMTP module - "Unable to send e-mail..." and "A test e-mail has been sent..."

Tags: emails, users

I am using the SMTP module (7.x-1.0) on Drupal 7. The site is hosted on a cloud server on which I've installed LAMP. My SMTP config settings are:

- SMTP server:  smtp.gmail.com
- SMTP port:  465
- Use encrypted protocol:  SSL
- Username: example@gmail.com
- Password: [password]
- E-mail from address: example@gmail.com

When I try to send a test email, I get two messages and an error in the "Reports > Recent log messages":

1. A test e-mail has been sent to example@gmail.com. You may want to check the logs for any error messages.
2. Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.
3. Error sending e-mail (from example@gmail.com to example@gmail.com).

The email is NOT sent. However, the email appears in "Reports > Maillog" (Maillog module).

There is an error in /var/log/apache2/error.log:

> sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found

Update/Edit:

- I was under the impression that the SMTP module avoids the need for
  Sendmail.I thought, the whole point was that it uses an external SMTP
  server. I found the following issue by the way:
  drupal.org/node/1078106.

Comment: Related: [Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/17291/1908).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `sendmail` service is not installed.

Try the command `sudo apt-get install sendmail` via ssh to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email through Gmail's FTP from a webserver can sometimes be blocked by Google.

Login to the account in a web browser, then visit this link:  https://accounts.google.com/displayunlockcaptcha

After you've done the unlock captcha, try your smtp test again.

Answer (score 0):

enabling 'Allow less secure apps' on https://myaccount.google.com/security#activity page fixed the problem for me.

I found this solution from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2080923#comment-10019929).